# bxslider center pics in browser-window

Tags: bxslider

I'm using bxslider in my site. Very nice plugin but i want to center the image (different width) in the middle of the slider to the middle of the window. Like this:

[image: slider]

Could anybody help me with this? Or have anybody a tipp for another plugin, what does this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you want, but you could make each div containing the photo to a constant size and the resize the photo to fit. You would need to have the overall containing div say 500px and each photo containing div 100px. this would give an effect similar to what you wanted..

Comment: Example code would be used to make you answer clearer. Many people on this site use http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate javascript, css and html code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something like this

[SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/FJYJM/8/)

Check the Jquery involved in this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slider').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        pause: 2000,
        autoHover: true,
        controls: false,
        maxSlides:3,
        displaySlideQty: 3,
        moveSlideQty: 1,
        onAfterSlide: function (currentSlide, totalSlides, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
            var $middleSlide = currentSlide + 2;
            $('#slider li').css({
                width:200
            });
            $('#slider li:eq(' + $middleSlide + ')').animate({
                width: 150
            }, 100);
        }
    });

});
```